# Proving that the solution to $f^{\prime}(x) = \frac{1}{x^{2} + (f(x))^{2}}$ is bounded above.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, integral-inequality

I am given that $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ is the unique solution to the ODE:
$$f^{\prime}(x) = \frac{1}{x^{2} + (f(x))^{2}}$$
with $f(0)=1$ and I must prove that it is bounded.
I have already proven (using the fact that the derivative is always positive and the Mean Value Theorem) that it is monotonically increasing so is bounded below, specifically by $f(0)=1$. However, I am struggling to figure out how to show it is bounded above. One thought I had was to rearrange the ode to get $(f(x))^2$ the subject, however this doesn't seem like a valid method for some reason, I may just be overthinking it though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\int _0^{x}f'(t) dt \leq ...$$

> $f(x)\geq 1 \implies f'(x) \leq \frac 1{1+x^2} $ $$\int _0^{x}f'(t) dt \leq \int_0^x \frac {dt}{1+t^2} $$ $$f(x)-f(0)\leq \text{arctan}(x)\leq \pi/4$$

Comment: nice hint, just enough to understand :-)

Comment: To make sure I am taking the hint correctly, is it less than or equal to log(x) which is bounded above, hence f(t) is bounded above?

Comment: Log(x)? ,  f'(x) bounded above by some "nice" function..

Comment: @Thomas $$x^2+(f)^2\ge x^2$$  This implies that for $x>1$ we have $$\left|\int_0^x \frac1{t^2+(f(t))^2}\,dt\right|\le \left|\int_0^1 \frac1{t^2+(f(t))^2}\,dt\right|+\left|\int_1^x \frac1{t^2}\,dt\right|$$Since $f(0)=1$ the first integral converges and is independent of $x$.  The second integral is $1-1/x\le 1$

Comment: @Pratik We don't even need to use the fact that $f\ge 1$ (It is embedded).  All we need to use is that $f(0)=1$ and that $f\in C[0,\infty)$.  .See my previous comment for the rest.

Comment: You might consider removing the word "Hint" at the top of you post.

Comment: Your last bound should be $\pi/2$. I guess a typo.